# What is this number encoding called?

Tags: encoding, variable-length

I know some variable length number encodings
which share the core idea that 1s encode the payload length linearly.

```
0
10x
110xx
1110xxx
```

or with 1s and Xs interleaved:

```
0
1x0
1x1x0
1x1x1x0
```

With some minor modifications (7 Xs per 1 and 7 Xs at the end) we get:

```
0xxxxxxx
1xxxxxxx0xxxxxxx
1xxxxxxx1xxxxxxx0xxxxxxx
1xxxxxxx1xxxxxxx1xxxxxxx0xxxxxxx
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_quantity

or:

```
0xxxxxxx
110xxxxx 10xxxxxx
1110xxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
11110xxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
```

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

but they both scale linearly.
I wanted something that scales exponentially and 
can be decoded bitwise in forward direction
(no byte alignment, reverse decoding or random seeking needed)
so I came up with:

```
0
1x0
1x1xx0
1x1xx1xxxx0
1x1xx1xxxx1xxxxxxxx0
```

Has anyone an idea if this is a thing and what it is called?

Answer (score 0):

Such an encoding is used in UTF-8. It's called [Variable-width encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-width_encoding)